# Can't generate pdf from xhtml (xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0.jar)

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces, itext

i  want to genarate a pdf from an xhtml page with a command button , but the resault is a black empty page in the browser, i've search the web but didn't found like my case. 
i'm using : xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0.jar - Maven projet

PrintBean.java

```
    package com.ismo.gestionabsence.presentation;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
//import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; 

import org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

@ManagedBean(name = "printBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PrintBean implements Serializable  {



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int     code;
    private String client;


    public PrintBean()
    {}

        @PostConstruct
        public void init()
        {

            code=1;
            client="teste de client;";
        }








    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }


    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void createPDF()  {

        System.out.println("in");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(true);
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/simple-webapp/faces/print.xhtml;jsessionid="+session.getId()+"?pdf=true";
        System.out.println("url");
        try {

            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(new URL(url).toString());

        //  renderer.setDocument(new File(url));
            renderer.layout();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("content-Disposition", "inline: filename=\"facture.pdf\"");
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            renderer.createPDF(outputStream);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
    public void test()
    {System.out.println("test");}

}
```

test.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
>
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>



<title>test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="form" >
button <h:commandButton value="print" action="#{printBean.createPDF}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>



</html>
```

The page to print , print.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Facture </title>
<link
    href="css/facture.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <h1>
        FACTURE
    </h1>
    <h3>Facture</h3>
    </header>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Client</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputText value="CodeL : #{printBean.code}"></h:outputText></td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{printBean.client}"></h:outputText></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td>Total: </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <footer>

    <p>
        Faculté des Sciences  <a rel="nofollow" 
            href="mailto:vdap.vv@gmail.com">Courriel: vdap.vv@gmail.com </a>
    </p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The stack error :

```
WARNING: Flying Saucer: No configuration files found in classpath using URL: xhtmlrenderer.conf, resorting to hard-coded fallback properties.
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.zzRefill(Lexer.java:1634)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.yylex(Lexer.java:1865)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.next(CSSParser.java:1807)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.la(CSSParser.java:1819)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.stylesheet(CSSParser.java:159)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.parseStylesheet(CSSParser.java:89)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:78)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.getStylesheet(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:174)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.readAndParseAll(StyleReference.java:123)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.setDocumentContext(StyleReference.java:107)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:182)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:145)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:141)
    at com.ismo.gestionabsence.presentation.PrintBean.createPDF(PrintBean.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If someone can expalin what to do to fix this , i'll be grateful !!
Regards, and excuse my english !!
 An image to explaine more the situation : [the pdf is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4RC1.png)

Comment: That is not how you make invoices with iText. Flying Saucer doesn't support PDF/A, Accessibility,... Read [the ZUGFeRD tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/7-creating-pdf-invoices-comfort) to learn how you should use iText. Why are you reinventing the wheel if someone has already done all the work from A to Z?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: To save costs? Customers want to pay less and less and to be able to provide a viable service, costs have to be low. Couple of years ago we requested a quote (pdfHTML was not available yet btw) and the price per PDF we had to pay was simply to high. There was no business case then. For me (indeed without the PDF/A) xhtmlrenderer with the old iText technically still works fine.

Comment: @Kukeltje If you want a perpetual license, the cost is high for low volumes. If you pay per use, the cost is cents per document.